# Pokergame with PHP and Jquery - Browser-Back-Button behaviour

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, browser

For practicing reasons I programmed a little Texas Holdem Game in PHP with some JQuery Animations. Every action (bet, fold, check, raise, call) is submitted via a HTML form to a PHP script.

Now unfortunately the user is able to just go back to the first betting round after seeing the whole board and the computer's cards and adjusting his betting structure accordingly by using the back-ubtton of the browser.

Is there a practical way for me to prevent this?

Thanks, 
Coffeehouse

PS:

A buttonscript is for example this:

```
if (isset($_POST['call']) AND $_SESSION['bettingcap'] == 1){
    $_SESSION['kapitalspieler'] -= $smallbet; // deduct money from player
    $_SESSION['pot'] += $smallbet; // add this to the pot
    $_SESSION['bettingcap'] = 0; // After call go to next street, so cap is 0
    $_SESSION['buttonmodus']=1; // I want to show only certain buttons
    $_SESSION['whichstreet']=$_SESSION['whichstreet']+1; // go to next street
    $_SESSION['animateagain']='yes'; // show JQuery Animation

}
```

Comment: without seeing the logic behind your game, people will just be guessing.

Comment: Bug? Sorry, I just signed up here. Did I post in the 'bug' forum?

Comment: I meant that adjusting bets after you have seen the cards is a cool bug. ;)

Comment: You could store their stepnumber in a session or something. Enter a new page -> store stepnumber in a session. Reenter the page->pagenumber is same as the stored number so no entry!

Comment: Yes, that would work too. But then that means if somebody hits the backbutton accidentally he would mess up his current game. Ideally what I was hoping to find is a way to that those actions are not stored in the history of the browser and that clicking back would bring the user back to the site he came from ... not just one step back in my poker game. Maybe submit buttons are the wrong choice, and maybe PHP is the wrong choice for that game overall?

Comment: You also might be interested in [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) and disable caching, so even if the user goes back, the page is fetched again and displays the current game state, not the previous one. Same for reloading a page BTW.

Answer (score 1):

You need to invalidate the request. That means one request follows after the other.

You do this by storing all requests of that user in the game.

If a new request is send, it can be only added at the end.

You can create the game in memory by initializing it and the pass in all events from all sides until a specific one.

This model does allow you to prevent cheating as well as re-playing a game like in a view mode of previous games.

- 00 created game   ID:#7575
- 01 player joined  seat:1; ID:#12
- 02 player joined  seat:2; ID:#56
- 03 player joined  seat:3; ID:#87
- 04 deck shuffled  order:the cards order here.
- 05 ...

So you keep these events and if a new request is send by a user you can check if it is okay with the current situation or not.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this will work.

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    window.history.forward();
    function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload="noBack();"
    onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload="">
```

From [link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/disable-back-button-browser-javascript/)

Comment: Yea that works fine. Unfortunately he could still cheat by turning off javascript then.

Comment: That is true, if you want to block this, I'd do something with sessions on server side and store at which step the user is or something in this way